# Dual citizenship entering Canada with expired Canadian passport

Tags: passports, canada, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens

My 13 year old daughter's Canadian passport expired in May of this year, I totally forgot that it needed to be renewed...  She has a valid Japanese passport as well as a green card, we live in the states.  Can she enter Canada using her Japanese passport, and then we will renew her Canadian in the fall when we return?  Should we bring the expired one with us?  Or can I start the process now, and then have it sent to the address we are staying in Canada?  Thanks

Comment: Enter Canada from where, by what means?

Comment: Ok so we are either going to drive through New Brunswick, or fly. I haven't totally decided yet....I am a Canadian but my husband is Japanese so the kids have dual passports.  Unfortunately they all have to be renewed at different times.  So, this time I forgot....

Comment: also we are just going to visit Canada for a couple of weeks to visit family

Comment: also she does have a Canadian Citizenship card..

Comment: When are you traveling? Can't you get your daughter a new Canadian passport while you are in the US?

Comment: not enough time.....we are traveling in about two weeks

Answer (score 8):

Unlike in the US, she can enter Canada on a valid Japanese passport even though she is a citizen of the country. Additionally, since Japanese citizens do not require a visa to enter the country, you won't have to apply in advance either.

I would bring the expired passport with me just in case since it is still proof of citizenship. You can apply for a new passport at any of the passport offices once you are in Canada.

[It is recommended that you enter Canada on a Canadian passport if you are a Canadian citizen](http://travel.gc.ca/returning/customs/entering-canada) but other valid documentation that establishes your legal right to enter Canada would also work. In this case, you can show the immigration officer your expired Canadian passport in addition to your valid Japanese passport to satisfy the legal requirement.

Comment: *Unlike in the US, she can enter Canada on a valid Japanese passport even though she is a citizen of the country* this is interesting, do you have a source ? I guess there's no way for the IO to know if you're a citizen or not if you're entering with a foreign passport ?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link that provides some more information.

Comment: @Blackbird57: They could. For example, if the passport says you were born in Canada, then that pretty much implies you are a Canadian citizen.

Comment: As far as I know, a regular Canadian passport is only issued to Canadian citizens.